# Return multiple dictionaries from the function in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, return

I am trying to understand how I can return several dictionaries from a function. If I print out **data_dict** in the function itself, I get five dictionaries. If data_dict will be returned from the function, stored in a variable and then printed out, only the last dictionary will be shown. How can all five dictionaries be returned?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

source = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

pattern = re.compile(r'window.__WEB_CONTEXT__={pageManifest:(\{.*\})};')
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
dictData = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
jsonData = json.loads(dictData)


def get_reviews():

    data_dict = {}
    for locations in jsonData['urqlCache']['669061039']['data']['locations']:
        for data in locations['reviewListPage']['reviews']:
            data_dict['reviewid'] = data['id']
            data_dict['authoridtripadvisor'] = data['userId']
            userProfile = data['userProfile']
            data_dict['author'] = userProfile['displayName']    
            print(data_dict)
    #return data_dict

reviews = get_reviews()
print(reviews)
```

Thank you for all suggestions!

Comment: `return dict1, dict2, dict3`

Comment: your proble is that in `data_dict` you can keep only one dictionary. You would have to create list for all dictionares and `append()` every dictionary to this list, and return this list of dictionares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that in `data_dict` you can keep only one dictionary.

You have to create list for all dictionares

```
all_dictionaries = []
```

and `append()` every dictionary to this list

```
all_dictionaries.append(data_dict)
```

and `return` this list

```
return all_dictionaries
```

And  inside `for`-loop you have to create new dictionary for new data. You can't use one `data_dict` and replace elements in this dictionary.

---

```
def get_reviews():

    all_dictionaries = []

    for locations in jsonData['urqlCache']['669061039']['data']['locations']:
        for data in locations['reviewListPage']['reviews']:

            data_dict = {}

            data_dict['reviewid'] = data['id']
            data_dict['authoridtripadvisor'] = data['userId']
            userProfile = data['userProfile']
            data_dict['author'] = userProfile['displayName']    
            print(data_dict)

            all_dictionaries.append(data_dict)

    return all_dictionaries
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: See @Furas's answer but pretty much the same thing (didn't see the other answer before hitting submit)

If you know the number of dictionaries you want to return ahead of time, you can return them like this:

```
def get_reviews():
    # ...
    return dict1, dict2, dict3
```

and then use the result like this:

```
d1, d2, d3 = get_reviews()
```

but if you want to return an arbitrary number of results back you should return a list containing all of your dictionaries:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

source = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

pattern = re.compile(r'window.__WEB_CONTEXT__={pageManifest:(\{.*\})};')
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
dictData = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
jsonData = json.loads(dictData)


def get_reviews():
    data = []
    for locations in jsonData['urqlCache']['669061039']['data']['locations']:
        for data in locations['reviewListPage']['reviews']:
            data.append({
                'reviewid': data['id'],
                'authoridtripadvisor': data['userId'],
                'author': data['userProfile']['displayName'] 
            })

    return data

reviews = get_reviews()
print(reviews)
```

Comment: sometimes it happen to me too - I press `submit` and then I see other answers or comments :) We have little different code and it can be useful.